# After Rooting my phone, I get a black screen, followed by "[app] has stopped working" for every application, any idea what could be going on?

Tags: rooting, samsung

I just rooted my Samsung Galaxy G4 I9500 today. It was working fine, I even restarted it a few times just to test everything was going nice and dandy. I also installed two apps to see if SuperUser was working properly (busybox and titaniumBackup) and both seemed to work fine.

Now, while trying to make a nandroid backup I entered recovery mode and touched "reboot device now". Afterwords, the device stopped starting properly.

As described in the title, the screen remains black with messages popping up saying something like "[x] app has stopped working". Trying to turn off the device gives me the usual windows (turn off/airplane mode/restart). Also, I can change the volume. Any idea of what could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could possibly be owing to a) wrong TWRP version b) Corrupted TWRP c) method of flashing TWRP

- You could download the [TWRP for your device](https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxys4internationalexynos.html).  I am ssuming you have the exynos version (recheck your device [Phone Info Samsung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo) or any other app which gives you chipset information can help)
- Verify MD5
- Flash using Odin or `dd` method. Link above has directions for both. Sometimes, flashing it by other methods doesn't work well with Samsung devices

**EDIT**: I am glad that you were able to fix with a factory reset using appropriate TWRP.

- Now, to restore data from the image created, select *Restore> choose location of image >Advanced Restore> data* (only-don't check anything else).
- Use above method when restoring data to the same ROM from which you took back up NOT across different ROMs or different android versions.
- This should help you learn [TWRP Guide](http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://www.addictivetips.com/android/what-is-twrp-how-to-install-use-it-on-android-devices-guide/&ei=O2xzmCpa&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=520&ts=1451280034&sig=ALL1Aj6jN3XHR81H8L1hP3J9GW-9ltyFXw)

Comment: I didn't download TWRP or any custom recovery, so I have the factory default "recovery mode" that comes with the Samsung. You think that flashing a TWRP could help? (P.S. thank for the answers :) )

Comment: I already have a vague idea of how to install TWRP and how to make a nandroid-backup, but those are not the problem I am currently facing. My problem is that when I turn on my phone, all my applications "close" and the screen remains black, meaning it's not booting correctly. I am not sure exactly what's going on. I just mentioned recovery mode because it happened after I accessed "samsung's stock recovery mode", but I'm not sure if that's related. I am only asking to see if someone has any idea of what could be going wrong or how could I fix it.

Comment: Well, I simply downloaded TWRP and did a full factory memory wipe. It deleted all my data and contacts, BUT the important part is that I can use my phone once more, which I compulsorily need on my everyday routine. Most of the information there was useless anyways. (note: I made a backup of my data on a pendrive using TWRP before clearing everything, but I have no idea how to recover it.) All and all, thank you a lot for your comments Beeshyams, they really helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I flashed cmw12.1. 
I backed up that Rom and when I rebooted I got same message as you.. Everything saying "stopped working!". 
Later I noticed that my nadroid backup was on internal storage and I was running out of space. 
I deleted that backup and everything went fine. 
Move that backup file to external sd card and try rebooting again.. 
Hope that would fix it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly, that's unlikely the case because I have free space (I deleted games like candy crush before entering recovery mode). Besides, I can not access the files in my phone, since after booting the screen becomes black and doesn't load anything.

Comment: If you get like "system ui stopped working" or other system apps then what I said may be the case. 
If you are using TWRP, it has a file browser. Make sure to have minimum of 500mb internal storage.

Comment: Since I am new at this, I used the most basic of chain-root, which only flashes the phone. It doesn't install any recovery tool, like TWRP. Maybe I should try to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Reset your app preferences. To do it Follow these steps.

1. Goto settings and open apps
2. On the upper part(different for every phone) look for three lines or dots. Tap on it and reset app preferences.